# Swap classes after resizing the window

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I am trying to swap the class when the browser get's resized.

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 768) {
            $('.toggle-menu').addClass('menu-right');
            $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('menu-top');
        }
        if($(window).width() < 768){
            $('.toggle-menu').addClass('menu-top');
            $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('menu-right');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: Apart from closing `}`, Your code should work

Comment: i dont know, it just doesn't work. it does nothing...

Comment: Do you have the jquery library referenced?

Comment: Why are exactly 768px not included?

Comment: I have, i am using jquery just a bit above this code, and it works fine... 
Oh thx, there is a = missing^^

Comment: You should be using some sort of throttle or debounce function, because $(window).resize() will be called multiple times during resizing.

Comment: your resize function doesn't close.. the last like should be `})` instead of `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('.toggle-menu').addClass('menu-right');
        $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('menu-top');
    }
    if($(window).width() < 768){
        $('.toggle-menu').addClass('menu-top');
        $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('menu-right');
    }
})
```

You forgot ")" after last "}"
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L1nh6f3L/) Example